# Need Help Having PHP File Upload To Upload File Under The User's Username

Tags: php, file-upload

I have a program that requires each user to upload their own image. That image must be, (their username).png. For example: testuser123.png. The PHP script that automatically enter's the user's username is

```
<?=$_SESSION['Username']?>
```

Basically, I need the file to be saved as

```
<?=$_SESSION['Username']?>.png
```

How would I do this with this certain script though? Any help would be greatly appreciated! The problem I have is I don't know where to put that part of the code, and I'm not sure if it would even work. I know my code has to be edited a bit, but I don't know how.

```
<?php
$allowedExts = array("png");
$extension = end(explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]));
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/png")
&& ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 20000)
&& in_array($extension, $allowedExts))
  {
  if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
    {
    echo "Error: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
    }
  else
    {
    echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br>";
    echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br>";
    echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " kB<br>";
    echo "Stored in: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
    }
  }
else
  {
  echo "Invalid file";
  }
?>
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php

Comment: Why not just allow the user to upload any file name to the server, and when you copy the image to its permanent location in the web-directory, rename it to [username].png?

Comment: You aren't actually moving a file, you are moving data, when you move the data to it's final destination you get to choose the filename you would like it to be saved as, see the link above on move-uploaded-file.php

Comment: It needs to be automatic, I don't have the time to do this over 100,000 times. And it needs to secure, as there will be thousands of users using this.

Comment: @user2055774 - it will be automatic. It doesn't matter what the name of the file the user uploads, as you get to chose the name of the file when it is stored on your server. See the move_uploaded_file() documentation.

Comment: @runspired - actually move_uploaded_file() does move a file. When a user uploads a file, it is uploaded to the temporary directory specified in php.ini (setting name is "upload_tmp_dir"). When move_uploaded_file() is called, it copies it from the tmp directory to the permanent directory and deletes it from the tmp.

Comment: Is there a reason why you must remove this question to the point of fighting back other people's attempts to restore the question? The answer seems satisfactory, so why not accept it instead?

Answer (score 2):

When you upload a file through a form, it's uploaded to the server's temp directory. You need to move it to a proper directory in your website or it will be removed when the server does garbage collection. To do this, you'll need to use move_uploaded_file(). Here's what you would need, given your script as it is:

```
<?php
$allowedExts = array("png");
$extension = end(explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]));
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/png")
&& ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 20000)
&& in_array($extension, $allowedExts))
  {
  if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
    {
    echo "Error: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
    }
  else
    {
    echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br>";
    echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br>";
    echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " kB<br>";
    echo "Stored in: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];

    $path = "/path/to/directory";
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $path."/".$_SESSION['Username'].".png");

    }
  }
else
  {
  echo "Invalid file";
  }
?>
```